# Find and delete files, but leave X newest

Tags: linux, command-line

I would like to find specific files and remove them, but I need to leave the last 3 newest files. For example I have a structure like this and I have 5 `.sql` files.

```
├── db1
│   └── db.sql
├── db2
│   ├── db2.sql
│   └── db3.sql
├── db5.sql
├── emptydir1
├── emptydir2
├── emptydir4
├── emptydir5
├── emptyri3
├── filenam2
├── filenam3
├── filename
├── filename4
├── filename5
├── find_db.sh
└── noemptydir1
    └── database.sql
```

I would like to remove all `.sql` files and leave only the newest 3 (i.e `db.sql`, `db2.sql`, `db3.sql`) based on modification date.
I can find all this files with:

```
find . -name "*.sql" -type f -ls | sort
```

which returns all needed file. I can't use `-delete` file as it will delete all files and I need to keep the newest 3. I can use i.e `rm ls -t | awk 'NR>3'` but it won't delete my specific files. Is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT

The best option that worked for me in this case was to use:

```
rm `find . -name "*.sql" |  xargs ls -lt | awk '{print $NF}' | tail -n +4`
```

Comment: "it won't delete my specific files" - what happens instead?

Comment: @NicoHaase because it will delete files only in current directory and I need to remove files from directories deeper than I am

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. "leave the last 3 newest files" - that means, the last three per directory?

Comment: @NicoHaase updated, hope it's much cleaner now

Comment: If you can find the file with the 4th oldest mtime, just use it with `find . ! -newer "${fourth_oldest}" -delete`. You might want to add a `-type f`

Comment: @WilliamPursell not sure if this will work as intended. Let's say you have `directory1`. Inside this directory you have other directories which can have more directories etc and `.sql` files can be at different directories. Now, being in `directory1` I would like to delete all `.sql` files except 3 newest

Comment: @Frendom  Are you trying to keep 3 files in every subdirectory?  If you just want to keep 3 files total, `-newer` seems like the easy approach.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes, 3 files in total